Cascade delete from linked models in Isar database flutter
so i implemented a todo model in isar , where each todo task can have a taskgroup, while each taskgroup can have multiple tasks, i used links as stated in the documentation. But my issue now is how to implement cascade delete from the taskgroup, such that when a taskgroup is deleted every tasks linked to it is also deleted
